# React: Validate dynamic fields using Formik and Yup

Tags: reactjs, validation, formik, yup

I have a couple of fields dynamically generated which I need to validate. The validations required are presence check and type checking (only numbers).

Following is the Form:

```
export const CampaignForm = (index: number) => ({
  formId: 'CampaignForm',
  formField: {
    campaignName: {
      name: 'campaignName',
      label: 'Name of your Campaign',
      placeholder: "Campaign's Name",
      requiredErrorMsg: 'Campaign name is required',
    },
    startDate: {
      name: 'startDate',
      label: 'Start Date',
      placeholder: 'Enter Start Date for Campaign',
      requiredErrorMsg: 'Start Date is required',
    },
    endDate: {
      name: 'endDate',
      label: 'End Date (Optional)',
      placeholder: 'Enter End Date for Campaign',
      requiredErrorMsg: 'Please enter a valid End Date',
    },
    ruleValue: {
      name: `campaignRules[${index}].value`,
      label: 'Value',
      placeholder: 'Select value',
      requiredErrorMsg: `Value for Rule ${index + 1} can't be left blank`,
    },
  },
})
```

I have defined following validation schema:

```
export const CampaignEditValidationSchema = Yup.object({
  campaignName: Yup.string().required(campaignName.requiredErrorMsg),
  startDate: Yup.date().nullable().required(startDate.requiredErrorMsg),
  content: Yup.string().required(content.requiredErrorMsg),
  ruleValue: Yup.string().required(ruleValue.requiredErrorMsg),
})
```

"ruleValue" is the dynamic validation I want. The problem is that despite value being present in the "Value" field Formik is still complaining about 'missing value'.

[image]

This is the Formik component I have:

```
const FormikLabelledTextInput: React.FC<IFormikLabelledTextInputProps> = (
  props,
) => {
  const [field, meta] = useField(props)
  console.log('My field:', field, ' and meta:', meta)
  const _renderErrorText = () => {
    const touched = meta.touched
    const error = meta.error
    if (touched && error) {
      return error
    } else return null
  }

  const error = _renderErrorText()

  return (
    <Container>
      <Label htmlFor={props.name}>
        <BodyText>{props.label}</BodyText>
      </Label>
      <Spacer height={6} />
      <ErrorSpan>{error}</ErrorSpan>
      <FormikTextInput isError={error !== null} {...field} {...props} />
    </Container>
  )
}
```

These Rules are laid down using Field Array:

```
<FieldArray name="campaignRules">
        {(fieldArrayProps) => {
          const { push, remove } = fieldArrayProps
          const { campaignRules } = fieldArrayProps.form.values
          return (
            <RulesBody>
              {campaignRules?.map((rule, index) => {
                return (
                  <RuleCard
                    key={rule.id}
                    ruleInfo={rule}
                    ruleNumber={index}
                    onDelete={remove}
                  />
                )
              })}
            </RulesBody>
          )
        }}
      </FieldArray>
```

RuleCard contains the FormikLabelledTextInput

```
const RuleCard: React.FC<ICardProps> = ({ ruleInfo, ruleNumber, onDelete }) => {
  return (
    <Card>
      <Header>
        <H3>{`Rule ${ruleNumber + 1}`}</H3>
        <Trash onClickHandler={() => onDelete(ruleNumber)} />
      </Header>
      <Spacer height={16} />
      <Row>
        <FormikLabelledTextInput
          type="text"
          name={CampaignForm(ruleNumber).formField.ruleValue.name}
          label={CampaignForm(ruleNumber).formField.ruleValue.label}
          placeholder={CampaignForm(ruleNumber).formField.ruleValue.placeholder}
        />
      </Row>
    </Card>
  )
}
```

The expected result is that if for Rule X, rule value is defined Formik shouldn't complain about the missing value.